# Actionscript 2.0 element.text always outputs "00"

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2, cs3

I'm fighting against a strange behaviour with my actionscript!
After setting the four integer variables from the MovieTimer sprite (hour, minute, second, mili-sec) and concate them i got always double zero: 00

```
    stop ();
    delete this.onEnterFrame;
    var str1;
    var str2;
    var mili;
    var second;
    var minute;
    var hour;
    var timer;

    mili = _root.MovieTimer.txt_mili.text;
    second = _root.MovieTimer.txt_sec.text;
    minute = _root.MovieTimer.txt_min.text;
    hour = _root.MovieTimer.txt_heures.text;

    timer = hour+' : '+minute+' : '+second+' : '+mili;

_root.MovieSpellFinish.TextTime.text = timer;
```

_root.MovieSpellFinish.TextTime.text outputs: 00

is there any solutions for this??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Embedded fonts you might need to check that you have the colon symbol embedded. Also you should check that the TextField is wide enough to accommodate the string you are trying to display.